# Proving two norms are not equivalent. Counterexamples. $V = C([0,1])$, $||f||_{\infty} = max |f(x)|$, $||f||_{*} = max |xf(x)|$.

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

$V = C([0,1])$, $||f||_{\infty} = max |f(x)|$, $||f||_{*} = max |xf(x)|$.
The question asks: if the two norms are equivalent? And if not, why?

How do I deduce whether the two norms are equivalent or not? And if not, how do I go about constructing a counterexample? I'm more interested in the thought process when trying to construct counterexamples rather than the actual counterexamples themselves as I often find it difficult to come up with them on my own.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, equivalence of norms means that $c\|f\|_{\infty} \le \|f\|_{*} \le C \|f\|_{\infty}$ for some $0<c<C<\infty$. It isn't that interesting when $\|f\|_{\infty}, \|f\|_{*}$ are $"$distant$"$ from $0$ or $+\infty$, hence to better understand whether or not two norms are equivalent, it is wise to look at functions with (one norm) close to $0$. It is obvious that $\|f\|_{*} \le \|f\|_{\infty}$, so that you should investigate the behaviour of functions $f$ such that their $\|\cdot\|_{*}$ norm is very close to $0$ and ask yourself whether $\|f\|_{\infty}$ norm need to be close to zero, too.